# Resource id in admin directory api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk

Hello can some one please tell me what is resource id in below image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ilm4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From [Retrieve a mobile device](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices#get_mobile_device) docs:

> The *resourceId* is a unique Google identifier for a device and is found
>   in the response of the [Retrieve all mobile devices
>   method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-mobile-devices#get_all_mobile_devices).